# How to retrieve verified channels from Youtube API V3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

Youtube has added a new feature to their website that flags verified Channels.
However, I couldn't find anything about it on their API Search. Anyone knows how can I use it on my searches?
If not, is it scheduled to be release soon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is not mentioned in the Youtube API guide. You don't read this from Youtube API because if you check [Verfication badgest in Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046484?hl=en) this is more focused on content creators as you need 100k subscribers before you can request to be verified.

Check the [Youtube Engineering Blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/) for announcements or you can [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround may be to get the JSON representation of the channel page (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTubeHelp?pbj=1 or https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMDQxm7cUx3yXkfeHa5zJIQ?pbj=1) and then look for a list with "ownerBadges" as its key (buried somewhere deep) and an entry with "metadataBadgeRenderer":{"style":"BADGE_STYLE_TYPE_VERIFIED"}.

The downside is these demand cookies and such.